# Is there any method or place in jquery where I can write method that will call after page removed from Dom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, cordova, jquery-mobile

In my application there are various pages. In my one page I had used

```
intervalID = setInterval(function(){getResponse();}, timer);
```

Now Suppose On click of back button I want to cancel that timer. Where should I write `clearInterval(intervalID);`?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: If your page isn't displayed anymore, the script is stopped and removed. You don't have to clear intervals.

Comment: Yes page is not displayed anymore after on back click but still on console I can see response after particular interval say after 10 sec if I I assign timer = 10000;

Answer (score 0):

your intervalID reference will be automatically destroyed when you change the page (like any other reference): anyway if you need to perform a generic action before a page change just use `onbeforeunload` event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

(just note that also a refresh of the page itself will trigger this event)

Comment: after using <script type="text/javascript">
  
   window.onbeforeunload = function(e)
   {
       clearInterval(intervalID);  
   };
  
  </script>  still not solve issue

Comment: If I add alert inside window.onbeforeunload = function(e) { then also that alert is not displayed.

Comment: from doc page:  *[...] calls to window.showModalDialog(), window.alert(), window.confirm() and window.prompt() methods may be ignored during this event.* - try to use `onunload` event instead

Comment: Ok suppose that method are ignored according to docs, but still timer is not cancelled in my case. Whats wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

If you're having Single-Page App (sounds like it) which is using push/popstate for handling history, then you can go with:

```
window.onpopstate = function() {
  clearInterval(intervalID);
}
```

Comment: @zovona Thanks for response, No my application is not single-page app, but window.onpopstate also does not solve issue.

Comment: I'm just wondering how an interval can sustain if you're making a new HTTP request with completely new content?